# byte[] to string in C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a project which is using (I assume) .NET Core. I have a library which stores securely key-pair values. The key is string and the value should be a byte[], so I have to convert the string that I want to store as byte[]:

```
bytes[] my_bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(txtSomeInfo.Text)
```

The problem is when i retrieve the value, because is an byte[] array i should convert it back to string like this:

```
my_string = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(my_bytes)
```

I found it some answers in Stack Overflow, but... I can't use it just like that because this version of GetString method of System.Text.Encoding is asking for two additional parameters: `int index, and int count`

How can I get my string back?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
my_string = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(my_bytes, 0, my_bytes.Length);
```

As Jon points out in the comments, the C# naming standards use camelCase for local variables so you should rename `my_bytes` and `my_string` to `myBytes` and `myString` respectively.

Comment: I think you mean `Length` rather than `Count`. (But otherwise, yes, this is what's needed. I'd personally fix the naming convention as well, but...)

Comment: Don't worry, I actually not using those names for variables in my project, so feel free to edit them if you wish.